# Calculus proof problem.

Tags: calculus

Could someone verify my argument?

> Let $f: [a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous and $f(x) \geq 0$ for all $x \in [a,b]$, and assume $\int_{a}^{b} f(t) dt = 0$. Prove that $f(x) = 0$ on $\forall x \in [a,b]$.

New sketch

$-\epsilon + f(x_0) < f(x) < \epsilon + f(x_0)$

$(-\epsilon + f(x_0))(b-a) < 0 < (\epsilon + f(x_0))(b-a)$

$  f(x_0) < \epsilon$

Take $\epsilon = f(x_0)$.

Comment: Your "proof" is wrong. Suppose the contrary and get a contradiction.

Comment: So assume $f \neq 0$?

Comment: Assume that $f(x_0)>0$ for some $x_0$ and use the definiton of continuity.

Comment: As @njguliyev said. Find an interval around $x_0$ over which the function is non-zero.

Comment: How about now? Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Your proof is wrong. The comments indicate what you should do, but check what you're writing in your proof and see *why* it is wrong.

You write "we know $\exists N$ such that $0 \leq f(x) \leq N \leq M$ for some $c \in [a,b]$". This doesn't make sense: $c$ doesn't show up anywhere, and furthermore $M$ is the maximum of $f$, so obviously such an $N$ exists: $M$ itself will do.

Then "$0 = \int_a^b f(c)dx$" also looks weird: you plugged in one particular $x$-value (namely $c$) into the integral. That needs to have no meaningful relation with the original integral.

Comment: yes, plugging in $c$ was a stupid move. I don't know why I did that.